# Reference a column by a variable

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I want to reference a table column by a variable while creating another column but I can't get the syntax:

```
    t0 = Table.FromRecords({[a = 1, b = 2]}),
    c0 = "a", c1 = "b",
    t1 = Table.AddColumn(t0, "c", each([c0] + [c1]))
```

I get the error *the record's field 'c0' was not found*. It is understanding `c0` as a literal but I want the text value contained in `c0`. How to do it?

## Edit

I used this inspired by the accepted answer:

```
    t0 = Table.FromRecords({[a = 1, b = 2]}),
    c0 = "a", c1 = "b",
    t1 = Table.AddColumn(t0, "c", each(Record.Field(_, c0) + Record.Field(_, c1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
let
    t0 = Table.FromRecords({[a = 1, b = 2]}),
    f = {"a","b"},
    t1 = Table.AddColumn(t0, "sum", each List.Sum(Record.ToList(Record.SelectFields(_, f))))
in
    t1
```

Comment: The `_` usage and meaning was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

try using an index as below

```
let t0 = Table.FromRecords({[a = 1, b = 2]}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(t0, "Index", 0, 1),
c0 = "a",
c1 = "b",
t1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "c", each Table.Column(#"Added Index",c0){[Index]} + Table.Column(#"Added Index",c1){[Index]} )
in t1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Expression.Evaluate` is another possibility:

```
= Table.AddColumn(t0, "c", each Expression.Evaluate("["&c0&"] + ["&c1&"]", [_=_]) )
```

Please refer to this article to understand the `[_=_]` context argument:

[Expression.Evaluate() In Power Query/M](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/02/06/expression-evaluate-in-power-querym/)

[This article](https://ssbi-blog.de/blog/technical-topics-english/the-environment-concept-in-m-for-power-query-and-power-bi-desktop-part-3/) explains that argument specifically:

> Inside a table, the underscore `_` represents the current row, when working with line-by-line operations. The error can be fixed, by **adding `[_=_]`** to the environment of the *Expression.Evaluate()* function. This **adds** the **current row** of the table, in which this formula is evaluated, **to** the **environment** of the statement, which is evaluated inside the *Expression.Evaluate()* function.