# How to implement indirection

Tags: powerquery, m

How does one indirectly refer to anything?  In my case it's a column name.  The "Field Access" section of the language doc left me with no clue.

For example

```
let
    OriginalStrings = "some string with {tkn1} and/or {tkn2}"
    ,ParamTable = [tkn1 = "this", tkn2 = "that"]
    ,Result = List.Accumulate(Record.FieldNames(ParamTable),OriginalStrings
                             ,(txt,current) => Text.Replace(txt,"{"&current&"}",ParamTable[current]))
in
    Result
```

This results in: Field 'current' of record not found.  What I want is the value of 'current' as an identifier and not the literal.

The code above should result in "some string with this and/or that"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825560/reference-a-column-by-a-variable/61832437#61832437), `Expression.Evaluate` may work for what you're after.

Replace `ParamTable[current]` with

```
Expression.Evaluate("ParamTable["&current&"]", [ParamTable=ParamTable])
```

Check out the **Expression.Evaluate() and non global environments** section of [this article](https://ssbi-blog.de/blog/technical-topics-english/the-environment-concept-in-m-for-power-query-and-power-bi-desktop-part-3/) for more clarity about the environment argument.